# Why is WinRAR 5 not giving me an option to use RAR5 format and only RAR4?

Tags: windows-10, rar, winrar

I just realized something. I recently purchased the WinRAR v.5.60 archive software:

[image]

But when I right-click some file that I want to `RAR` and then click `Add to archive`, the popup window offers me only the `RAR4` format:

[image]

Why so?

Comment: Isn't "RAR", the default selection, the current RAR version, the RAR4 option being for the old format?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: Hmmm. Idk. The previous version had `RAR`, `RAR5` and `ZIP` selection there.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/770370/what-is-the-difference-between-rar-and-rar5-compression

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: OK, so you just proved my point. Then why is it showing `RAR4` instead of `RAR5`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm assuming "RAR" means RAR5 because it's what makes sense as the new default. Something similar to what happened with Microsoft Office some time ago: The new default is .docx but users can still save in the old . doc format. The previous version probably hadn't RAR5 as the default yet but as an option. But you can check whether my assumption is correct or not: https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/03/identify-open-rar5-archives/

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: Oh, OK. Thanks for that ghacks link. I just tried it and yes, I can confirm, now `RAR` in that first screenshot I showed stands for `RAR5`. (Although, note that your first link to another post was saying a different thing -- that `RAR` stands for v.2.9., which it used to do before this latest version, I guess. Which is somewhat confusing, who uses it a lot.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After verifying the file properties using the method described here https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/03/identify-open-rar5-archives/ we could conclude that:

- The "RAR" option shown in the screenshot and selected by default is indeed the same as the "RAR5" option of previous versions.
- The option explicitly mentioning "RAR4" refers to the old format that now is an option but not the default.